# Remove multiple Objects from an array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, object

I have an object, which contains an array of object, and I would to remove some objects from the createValue array.

I would like to be able to delete multiple objects at the same time. I tried with splice but when I delete it is written undefined.

here is my code :

```
    let obj2 = {
                projectId: 0,
                gridId: 0, 
                createValues : [
                {
                 "field": "ID",
                 "value": "40212"
                },
                {
                "field": "FLD_STR_101",
                "value": "TEST1"
                },
                {
                "field": "FLD_STR_101",
                "value": "TEST1"
                },
                {
                "field": "FLD_STR_101",
                "value": "TEST1"
                },
                {
                "field": "Table",
                "value": "TEST1"
                },
                {
                "field": "FLD_STR_101",
                "value": "TEST1"
                },
                {
                "field": "log",
                "value": "TEST1"
                },
               {
                "field": "crea",
                "value": "TEST1"
               },
               {
                "field": "off",
                "value": "TEST1"
                },
               ]

        };


       obj2.createValues.splice(0,2)
       obj2.createValues.splice(4,4)
```

I would like to delete the off, crea, log, table and id. Basically with splice i deleted everything but the "Table" field is in the middle so I do not know how to

Comment: yes, but let s say I would like to delete  them in a different order

Answer (score 1):

Here I am removing duplicate objects according to value, you can edit this code to delete multiple objects according to your needs.

```
let newArray = [];
let removeDuplicate = [];
obj2.createValues.forEach(ele => {
   if (!removeDuplicate.includes(ele.value)) {
      removeDuplicate.push(ele.value);
      newArray.push(ele);
   }
})

const newObj = {...obj2, createValues: newArray}
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

The splice() method returns the removed item(s) in an array and slice() method returns the selected element(s) in an array, as a new array object.

You could use [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) or [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: well the delete is returning an undefined, it does not delete the object

Comment: Why don't you just filter them for the value you don't want exp: array.filter(x => x.value != "somevalue")

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using loops.

```js
let obj2 = {
                p: 0,
                id: 0, 
                create : [
                {
                 "f": "ID",
                 "v": "4"
                },
                {
                "f": "F",
                "v": "TEST1"
                },
                {
                "f": "F",
                "v": "TEST1"
                },
                {
                "f": "F",
                "v": "TEST1"
                },
                {
                "f": "T",
                "v": "TEST1"
                },
                {
                "f": "F",
                "v": "TEST1"
                },
                {
                "f": "log",
                "v": "TEST1"
                },
               {
                "f": "crea",
                "v": "TEST1"
               },
               {
                "f": "off",
                "v": "TEST1"
                },
               ]

        };


let array = []
obj2.create.forEach((value, index) => {
  
  if(value.field !== "ID" && value.field !== "log" && value.f !== "off" && value.field !== "crea" &&       value.f !== "Table") {
    array.push(value)
  }
 

})

obj2.create = array
console.log(obj2)
```

Comment: yes that is what I did, but let 's say I want to delete them not in the same order

Comment: How do you wish to delete them? By what?

Comment: I wish to delete them by field value.

Comment: @marizona I edited the answer, is this what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do it:

> `array.pop()` – Removes from the end of an Array.
> `array.splice()` – Deletes from a specific Array index.
> `array.shift()` – Removes from the beginning of an Array.
> `array.slice()` – Deletes unnecessary items and returns required items.
> `array.filter()` – Allows you to remove elements from an Array programmatically
> - [appdividend.com](https://appdividend.com/2022/06/17/javascript-remove-object-from-array/)

I would recommend using the filter method, it will return a new array given each condition inside it.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** There was a missing closing array tag ] in the question code, after the last element.

I'm not sure what have you tried with **Splice** if it was returning *undefined*, but here is a working solution of creating a new array, with removing elements on first 2 index values.

```js
let obj2 = {
  projectId: 0,
  gridId: 0, 
  createValues : [
  {
   "field": "ID",
   "value": "40212"
  },
  {
  "field": "FLD_STR_101",
  "value": "TEST1"
  },
  {
  "field": "Table",
  "value": "TEST1"
  },
 {
  "field": "hello",
  "value": "TEST1"
 }
  ]
};

const newObj2 = obj2.createValues.splice(2);// will delete first 2 elements
console.log(newObj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using filter, I have created function called "removeFieldFromArray" which will accept two parametes.

1. Array that needs to be modified (In you case obj2.createValues)
2. Array that will contain fields that you want to remove
   In your case :  ['off', 'crea', 'log', 'table', 'ID']
   Function will return modified array that will not have fields you have passed in second parameter.

   Here is the function :

   ```
    function removeFieldFromArray(array, fields) {
        return array.filter(r => !fields.includes(r.field))
    }
   ```

   Just overwrite obj2.create like this :

   ```
    obj2.create = removeFieldFromArray(obj2.create, ['off', 'crea', 'log', 'table', 'ID'])

    console.log(obj2)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.filter` to filter out those elements that does not meet a condition.

The function `filter` returns a new array with the elements that meet the condition.

```js
const obj = {                projectId: 0,                gridId: 0,                 createValues : [                {                 "field": "ID",                 "value": "40212"                },                {                "field": "FLD_STR_101",                "value": "TEST1"                },                {                "field": "FLD_STR_101",                "value": "TEST1"                },                {                "field": "FLD_STR_101",                "value": "TEST1"                },                {                "field": "Table",                "value": "TEST1"                },                {                "field": "FLD_STR_101",                "value": "TEST1"                },                {                "field": "log",                "value": "TEST1"                },               {                "field": "crea",                "value": "TEST1"               },               {                "field": "off",                "value": "TEST1"                },               ]        },
      targetValues = ["log", "off", "crea", "ID", "Table"],
      key = "field",
      filterHandler = o => !targetValues.includes(o[key]);

obj.createValues = obj.createValues.filter(filterHandler);

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let obj2 = {
            projectId: 0,
            gridId: 0, 
            createValues : [
            {
             "field": "ID",
             "value": "40212"
            },
            {
            "field": "FLD_STR_101",
            "value": "TEST1"
            },
            {
            "field": "FLD_STR_101",
            "value": "TEST1"
            },
            {
            "field": "FLD_STR_101",
            "value": "TEST1"
            },
            {
            "field": "Table",
            "value": "TEST1"
            },
            {
            "field": "FLD_STR_101",
            "value": "TEST1"
            },
            {
            "field": "log",
            "value": "TEST1"
            },
           {
            "field": "crea",
            "value": "TEST1"
           },
           {
            "field": "off",
            "value": "TEST1"
            }
           ]

    };

let filterValue = obj2.createValues.filter(function(em) {
    return (em.field !== "ID" &&
            em.field !== "Table" &&
            em.field !== "log" &&
            em.field !== "crea" &&
            em.field !== "off")
            
})

console.log('filterValue  : ', filterValue )
```

Comment: I would like to delete based on the value from of the "field". I edited my question maybe this is clear now.